# IIS caching and HTTP caching

Tags: caching, iis

What's the difference between

```
<caching enabled="true" enableKernelCache="true">
  <profiles>
    <add extension="*" location="Any" policy="CacheForTimePeriod" duration="00:30:00" varyByQueryString="*" varyByHeaders="Accept-Language" kernelCachePolicy="CacheUntilChange" /> 
  </profiles>
</caching>
```

and

```
<httpProtocol>
  <customHeaders> 
    <add name="Cache-Control" value="private, max-age=1800, must-revalidate" />
    <add name="Pragma" value="private, max-age=1800, must-revalidate" />
    <add name="Expires" value="1800" /> 
  </customHeaders>
</httpProtocol>
```

If I understand well, the first is for IIS (cache file on server, to answer quickly) and the second one is for proxy/client (ask a new version every 30 minutes) ?

What do you think about my cache policies ? I want to improve performance but because I have important fresh information every 30min, I set to 30 min every cache...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The Pragma header is implementation specific and secondary to the Cache-Control header (see http://www.w3.org/Protocols/rfc2616/rfc2616-sec14.html#sec14.32). Better to not use it.

Setting the cache to "private" prevents caching on proxies, you might want to set it to "public" for faster client response--this change is especially recommended if your content is served over HTTP rather than HTTPS ("public" is ignored in that case, unless SSL is cracked within for instance a corporate fire-wall).